Does the mitzvah of honoring one's parents extend to in-laws?
Does Kibud Av V'Em extend to one's mother-in-law and father-in-law? If so, is the obligation equivalent to honoring one's own birth parents?

Why would you think it does?  It doesn't even extend to adoptive parents . [Sotah 49a]

@Dov cites the SA to show that it is in fact an obligation....

Yes there are loads of sources for this...
A good starting point is the Tur YD 240:1:

וחייב לכבד חמיו דכתיב "אבי ראה גם ראה".
One is obligated to respect their father-in-law, as it is written, "See, my father ("avi"), also see".

The Beis Yosef, YD 240:38 explains this more clearly:

ומ"ש וחייב אדם לכבד חמיו ב"ה כ' כן בא"ח דכתיב "אבי ראה גם ראה" דוד אמר הכי לשאול וקרי ליה אבי מפני שהיה חמיו:
And regarding what [the Tur] writes, that one is obligated to respect their father-in-law, B"H writes this in Orchot Chaim, as it is written, "See, my father ("avi"), also see", Dovid says this to Shaul and calls him "avi" because he was his father-in-law.

The Aruch Hashulchan there (240:44) expands this to mother-in-law as well:

חייב אדם לכבד חמיו וחמותו, שהרי דוד קרא לשאול "אבי" דכתיב (שמואל א כד יא): "אבי ראה גם ראה". כן כתבו הטור והשולחן ערוך סעיף כ"ד (שולחן ערוך יורה דעה רמ, כד).
One is obligated to respect their father-in-law and mother-in-law, for David called Shaul "Avi", as it is written, "See, avi, also see". So writes the Tur and Shulchan Aruch Seif 24 (Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 240:24).

However, he questions this approach and proves that the term "avi" could just be a term of respect like Elisha called Eliyahu who was his main Rebbi.
